# check if ip address is used in .net

Tags: .net, windows, networking, arp

use case: .net app on a pc is setting the static ip address of a node in its own lan (via router/switch)

Before we let users set an ip address, we want to make sure that the address is not already used by some thing else.

We currently Ping the new address, if we get a response we assume its already in use, if not we allow the address setting.

When you ping an unused address, windows will not see a success and it will mess up its ARP cache. I figured that if I set the sender ip address in the ARP request to 0.0.0.0, the cache will remain clean. However I couldnt figure out how to do it with .net api.

Comment: What happens if a host firewall blocks the ping response?

Comment: both ends are within the same lan, so odds of firewall problems are negligible

Comment: If you are all on the same LAN can you ask the switch? Also, this seems like a job for dhcp, right?

Comment: we are setting the static ip for a node on the same lan as the pc. so dhcp server is not in the picture. for static we cant ask only the router/switch, we have to ask all the nodes in the lan for known potential ip conflicts

Comment: I still don't understand why dhcp wouldn't do the job. You can even run a dhcp server on a standard pc, you don't need specific hardware for this. And firewall problems might still arise, because it is a rather common feature of firewalls to block ping requests.

Comment: lets stick to the pc - router with dhcp server - node configuration. given this, how would you ask the dhcp server to look for ip conflicts? and i want this resolution to be done on the pc not the node (thats a different alternative)